# How can I get Magic Trees without recipes?

Tags: ios, magic-tree

Some of the Magic Trees listed in the Illustrated Book don't have Recipes. How do I grow these trees? Are there secret combinations to grow each one?

Comment: I find the best way to get a hold of Magic Trees is to ask discretely in a little corner store called a Bodega. Say it with me now, **Bo-De-Ga.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to combine three seeds of quality AAA, AAB or ABB, mixing them will result in a random magic tree from a selection of trees you can't get by recipe. The seeds can be in any order. I have no yet confirmed if including more A rank seeds means you get different trees.

Because A and B rank seeds create magic trees, I'd recommend only using C rank seeds to mix for other seeds (you *can* get random seeds above C rank this way). Consult this forum post for some more information: `http://119.205.200.248/forum/showpost.php?s=598202cf987e014ad56f937b296e0c0a&p=380378&postcount=33` (Can't linkify the URL)